# Precise Geolocation reporting using Google Measurement API

Tags: google-analytics, geolocation, measurement-protocol

I'm having issues with **Google Measurement Api**. I need to manually report ecommerce transactions to the analytics, and the only data i'm getting from the payment processor is Country Code (which is not precise enough for our analytics process) and IP address of person doing the purchase.

We've tried sending **uip** (User IP override) param but analytics ignores IP and does not extract the Geolocation from it.

We've tried using **geoid**, but as i said is not precise. We need city information too. I see that **geoid** can take integer as param which describes the precise location, but i don't know how to get to that number if only thing i have is IP address.

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know GA is ignoring the IP override? That's typically how it gets its geo data.

Comment: Well, i tried filtering the data from the date i've implemented UIP and i'm getting no country in analytic data.

Comment: Hmmm, all I can say is the `uip` param **is** the recommended way of doing exactly what you're asking. That use-case is why the feature was added in the first place. It may be worth [reporting this as a bug](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/entry?template=Measurement%20Protocol%20-%20Defect) if you're sure you don't have any other implementation errors.

Comment: I'll take a look again, i might be doing something wrong, but i'm not getting any errors when doing debug request.

Answer (score 0):

Which hit type do you use?
You must fulfill all mandatory fields of GA measurement protocol so the request could be accepted by GA.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters